# boost unique_ptr Deletor

Tags: c++, boost

If I want to create a `unique_ptr` of type `QueueList` (some self defined object), how do I define a deletor for it or is there already a template 'Deletor' I can use?

I want a `unique_ptr` so I can safely transfer the object between threads, without sharing it between the threads.

EDIT

```
boost::interprocess::unique_ptr<QueueList> LIST;  ///FAILS to COMPILE!!!

LIST mylist;
```

Compiler: MS Visual Studio 2003

ERROR:

error C2976: 'boost::interprocess::unique_ptr' : too few template arguments

error C2955: 'boost::interprocess::unique_ptr' : use of class template requires template argument list
       : see declaration of 'boost::interprocess::unique_ptr'

Comment: How do you allocate the QueueList objects? How it is supposed to eb deleted? Consider providing example code.

Comment: Could we have the compiler name/version as well as the exact error ? I don't see anything wrong here, apart from using all caps for non-macro.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a simple deleter class that just calls delete on any given object:

```
template<typename T> struct Deleter {
    void operator()(T *p)
    {
        delete p;
    }
};
```

You can then use it with unique_ptr like this:

```
boost::interprocess::unique_ptr<QueueList, Deleter<QueueList> > LIST;
```

Comment: Isn't this the default deleter?

Comment: Hmmm... Looks like boost doesn't have a default deleter.